# HQL Query with alias

Tags: java, database, hql, aliases

I am trying to execute an hql query with aliases

```
select **clbs.id as id**  
  from ClaimDO cl, ClaimBillSummaryDO clbs, HospitalDO h 
  where clbs.parentGuidObj.id=cl.id and h.id=cl.hospitalSeq and cl.id= '10721'
```

and I get the following error

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: , expected in SELECT
```

However the query runs without error if i remove the alias

```
select **clbs.id** 
  from ClaimDO cl, ClaimBillSummaryDO clbs, HospitalDO h
 where clbs.parentGuidObj.id=cl.id and h.id=cl.hospitalSeq and cl.id= '10721'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using mappings to join your entities? You might as well use native queries to do this. HQL would look more like the following. I have omitted the HospitalDO join since it doesn't look meaningful.

```
    select clbs.id from ClaimDO cl join cl.parentGuidObj clbs where cl.id = :id
```